# How to automatically call an api before each api call in axios in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

Suppose I want to call an api(for session) before each api call , api should be called automatically before any other api call.
How I can achieve this in axios in react.
I want to do it globally for whole project.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper around axios. You should usually do this anyway so that you can inject headers and other things specific to your application.

Here's a basic version of that.

```
let sessionStuffPromise = null;

function request(method, ...args) {
  if (!sessionStuffPromise) {
    // do your initial stuff and return a promise
    sessionStuffPromise = foo();
  }
  return sessionStuffPromise.then(() => {
    return axios[method](...args);
  });
}
```

Comment: where to put that common api call in my project so that it can be called automatically before any other api call ?

Comment: @NISHANTJAIN you use this function any time you want to make a request; it automatically ensures the `foo()` promise completes before making another request while also not making the `foo()` request more than once.

Comment: Where to put this function ? I want to set some api call globally in axios library that would be called automatically before any api call.